# Android - Custom Button Color Causes Unwanted Resize

Tags: xml, textview, android, android-button

Apparently changing this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/register"
    android:background="@color/bluegreen"
    android:text="Log In"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

to this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/register"

    android:text="Log In"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Results in the shrinking of the login button (and adding the missing line above causes the changes to revert back so I'm sure it's related to the line android:background="@color/bluegreen" ):

EXAMPLE IMAGE:

http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5519/10947007043_ea9389305d_b.jpg

### strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">omv</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="usernamehint">Username</string>
<string name="passwordhint">Password</string>
<color name="grey">#292929</color>
<color name="bluegreen">#43BFC7</color>
```

Comment: Please show us the full code then I can run it in my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase the size of the button, look into using a different value for your `android:layout_height`.  The following shows an example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/register"
    android:background="@color/bluegreen"
    android:text="Log In"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

You can play around with the value to get it where you want it to be.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

**Edit**

The reason that your button does not look the same as the default button is that the default uses a special image type that builds padding into the image.  This special image is called a [`9patch png`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) and is generally used for preventing the issue you are facing.  ADT supplies tools to convert a `png` into a `9patch`.  Standard colors do not change to `9patch`, thus the content appears as above.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Care to elaborate?

Comment: I'd like it to fill parent just as the button below it does... is that possible?

Comment: I just want to prevent it from shrinking when changing the color - not have it a fixed size.

Comment: Can I remove the padding? Even if I set both buttons to android:layout_height="40dp" it leaves padding on the right and left side of the button which causes it to look smaller than the other button. I simply need both buttons to look exactly the same and adding android:layout_height="40dp" to both still leaves us with unwanted padding.

Comment: @user3009687 Using a color for the background by default uses no padding.  What you're seeing on the left and right side is the effect of using `fill_parent` as the value for `android:layout_width`.  It stretches the button to fill the parent view (which in this case is the whole width of the screen).